# How to get size of a SXSSFWorkbook before calling its write() method?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to transfer an ArrayList(dynamic size) to a ByteArrayOutputStream based on the SXSSFWorkbook without a real WorkBook file.
I succeeded the code as below.

1.new a SXSSFWorkbook.

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
```

2.looping the ArrayList to fill out "wb" above.

3.transferring "wb" to a ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream( 6000 ); // my question is the buffer
wb.write(bos);
byte[] byteContent = bos.toByteArray();
bos.close();
wb.dispose();
// an API for users to download the real WorkBook file
// and the API needs a byte[] type for the 1st argument.
createDownloadUrl(byteContent, fileName);
```

It works, but I think the buffer(here is 6000) is supposed to equal the size of "wb", not a fixed number(eg. 6000 here).
My question is how to get size of "wb" without/before writing to a real WorkBook file?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just skip setting a size, and let Java auto-size it for you as it goes?

Comment: The initial size of an `ByteArrayOutputStream` is simply the initial size of the array. If `write` needs more bytes, then a new additional array of that size is taken and if ready all arrays will be put together. So the initial size must not be the exactly needed size. It should be not too small so not so much single arrays will be need but also not too big so not so much allocated memory will be not need then. A initial size of 1024 (1 k Byte) should be a good compromise.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies!
Does that mean ByteArrayOutputStream will automatically adjust its length like StringBuffer does, we don't have to worry about it?

Comment: I found the paper about ByteArrayOutputStream() Constructor 
"Creates a new byte array output stream. The buffer capacity is initially 32 bytes, though its size increases if necessary."
Thank  Gagravarr and  Axel Richter.